# Is a method pointer assignment thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

### *Example:*

Assume, I would have the following thread (please, don't take into account what's used in this example's thread context execution method, it's just for explanation):

```
type
  TSampleThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FOnNotify: TNotifyEvent;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    property OnNotify: TNotifyEvent read FOnNotify write FOnNotify;
  end;

implementation

procedure TSampleThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    if Assigned(FOnNotify) then
      FOnNotify(Self); // <- this method can be called anytime
  end;
end;
```

Then assume, I'd like to change the method of the `OnNotify` event from the main thread at any time I need. This main thread implements the event handler method as the `ThreadNotify` method here:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FSampleThread: TSampleThread;
    procedure ThreadNotify(Sender: TObject);
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.ThreadNotify(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // do something; unimportant for this example
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FSampleThread.OnNotify := nil; // <- can this be changed anytime ?
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FSampleThread.OnNotify := ThreadNotify; // <- can this be changed anytime ?
end;
```

### *Question:*

Is it safe to change a method, which can be called from a worker thread from another thread's context at any time ? Is it safe to do what is shown in the above example ?

I'm not precisely sure, if that's absolutely safe, at least since method pointer is actually a pair of pointers and I don't know if I can take it as an atomic operation.

Comment: Instead of doing that, leave it assigned always and use a 32 bit variable instead of type integer or native integer. Then assign to the integer a non-zero value or a zero value. If the integer values is non-zero then call the event otherwise do not call the event. That is a simple work-around.

Comment: @bobshacks, that's not safe on a multi-cpu (or multi-core) system unless you also cause a memory barrier every time you assigned that sentinel integer. With no barrier some of the CPU's will be using "stale" data from the cache for a while after the assignment. You need the `InterlockedXYZ` routines, but it could work.

Comment: True. Use the InterlockedExchange function to do the assignment. In this case even better is InterlockedIncrement and InterlockedDecrement. The other idea is to make a pointer to the method pointer. So make it a variable in the form and then pass a pointer to the variable to the thread and naturally do that using atomic functions. Then it is still just one pointer.

Comment: @bobshacks, thanks! I think I can handle that situation. This question I've asked just out of curiosity (actually, I'm not going to do this in real) and in a hope it might be helpful also to someone else, since method assigment is not so obvious and one can overlook this risk.

Comment: @CosminPrund It's actually not a problem for Delphi on Intel. For example, double checked locking works fine for Delphi on Intel because of that. Intel x86 and x64 has a strong memory model, and Delphi doesn't optimise or cache reads and writes from anything that can be visible globally (i.e. everything that's not a local variable).

Comment: @David, are you saying that the `InterlockedExchange` method would not be needed because the assignment of an integer is atomic and all reads/writes will be serialized? Because I don't buy that (without a link that is), since that would make all the `InterlockedExchange()` methods useless. The way I understand it it's because of multiple cores/cpus have multiple caches: even if the compiler doesn't reorder operations (relative to source-code order), even if the CPU doesn't reorder operations, there's still the issue of multiple CPU caches having different "views" of the same memory.

Comment: @Cosmin `InterlockedExchange` does more than simply set a value, it exchanges. You get back the previous value. So that's its use. If all you need to do is write a value, aligned pointer sized writes are atomic and don't tear. And the strong Intel memory model guarantees cache coherence. All bets are off, I agree, on hardware with weak memory models.

Comment: @David, links please, if you have them. I've read too many things about this, not all of them authoritative. Here's an example [Java Memory Model concerns on Intel and AMD systems](https://blogs.oracle.com/dave/entry/java_memory_model_concerns_on) hinting the memory model on those platforms is not all that strong. I guess I'm forming the most troublesome memory model possible in my head, and working with that: My CPU rearranges operations, has caches that might serve stale data yet it cherry-peeks my variables so I get false-sharing if those variables are close-together. Play safe.

Comment: @CosminPrund The Intel memory model is documented in the Intel docs. The Delphi side of things is not documented anywhere.

Comment: @David, I haven't found a clear statement on memory model in any of the Intel PDF manuals that I downloaded. Granted, I have no intention of writing a compiler any time soon, so 99% of it is irrelevant to me. I did find enough to "seed doubt". The SSE architecture introduced explicit instructions for manipulating the CPU cache, there's some talk about the "weak-ordered memory types".

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something as I'm faaaaaar from being any good with Threads programming in Delphi, but isn't it obvious that in such scenario the `FOnNotify` would run in a different Thread and that `if Assigned(FOnNotify) then FOnNotify(Self);` *should* be warped with `Synchronize`?

Comment: @kobik, yes, the code in the `ThreadNotify` method, which I've marked as *"do something; unimportant for this example"* when it's assigned to the `OnNotify` event must have been either thread safe (since it is called from a different thread context), or thread un-safe, but called through the `Synchronize` (typically access to VCL components). In all cases, I wouldn't personally use such construction in real; it's very tight to the (main thread) class. This specific notification case would be a good job for posting a message.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, it's not thread safe because that operation will never be "atomic". The `TNotifyEvent` is made up of two pointers, and those pointers will never be both assigned at the same time: one will be assigned, then the other will be assigned.

The 32 bit Assembler generated for a `TNotifyEvent` assignment is composed of two distinct assembler instructions, something like this:

```
MOV [$00000000], Object
MOV [$00000004], MethodPointer
```

If it were a single pointer then you'd have some options, since that operation is *atomic*: the options you have depend on how strong the memory model of the CPU is:

- If the CPU supports the "sequential consistency" model, then any read that happens after you write the memory will see the new value, guaranteed. If that's the case you can simply write your value, no need for Memory Barriers or the use of `Interlocked` methods.
- If the CPU is more relaxed about re-ordering stores and loads, then you need a "memory barrier". If that's the case, the easiest solution is to use [InterlockedExchangePointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Unfortunately I do not know how strong the memory model of current Intel CPUs is. There's some circumstantial evidence that suggest some re-ordering may take place, those the use of `Interlocked` would be recommend, but I haven't seen a definitive statement by Intel that says one or the other.

Evidence:

- Modern CPU's use "prefetch" - that automatically implies some level of load/store reordering.
- SSE introduced specific instructions for dealing with CPU cache.

Comment: That's what I thought. I was just wondering, if compiler doesn't treat them somehow *"magically"* as one pointer. If there's no such *"single pointer compiler magic"* behind, then it's of course unsafe. I could have check this in disassembly by myself (lazy me). Thanks for confirmation! [+1 & accept]

Comment: Does the builtin `OnTerminate` event carry the same risk? Granted, it's only called once per thread life. But AFAICS the RTL does not protect its assignment.

Comment: @Sertac, the `OnTerminate` method is called through the `Synchronize`, at least in Delphi 2009, so it's actually executed in the main thread's context, so there's no risk.

Comment: @TLama - My question is not about calling the assigned method, it's about assigning to the notification event.

Comment: @Sertac, calling of the assigned method is the main point of this problem. You can assign it however you want. That's thread safe, unless that assigned method is called from within a different thread context than the assigner is.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, why would the `OnTerminate` behave any differently? It's still a two-pointer deal, the compiler assigns it the same way. The risk is lower because it's only called once and even then it's called through `Synchronize`; None the less, if a 3rd thread (not the main thread and not the terminating thread) is assigning it, the risk is absolutely the same.

Comment: @Sertac, if you suspect something related to `OnTerminate`, there's a different bug that I ran into that might cause problems. There's a race condition in `Classes.ThreadProc` if multiple threads are exiting at the same time, causing some of them to NOT have the `FFinished := True`, even those they're terminated. Easily tested: create a bunch of threads without `FreeOnTerminate`, have them all wait on a manual-reset event, set them all to `Terminated`, signal the event then try to free all of the threads. Some of your threads will dead-lock in `TThread.Destroy` because `FFinished` is False.

Comment: @Cosmin - No, it's not about an actual case, but thanks for that. In any case I think I don't need a 3rd thread to break it, the `if Assigned(FOnTerminate)` test is done in the thread context, the main thread can then set the event to nil before the thread calls `Synchronize(CallOnTerminate)`. Or is this kind of problem not related with thread safety?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, I was sharing that information because I thought you had an actual problem with the `OnTerminate`; That's called from `TThread.DoTerminate` and `DoTerminate` is called immediately before setting `FFinished:=True`. The race condition affecting `FFinished` would surely affect `DoTerminate` as well, and that in turn would affect the `OnTerminate`.

Comment: @CosminPrund - wonderful, another episode in the saga of Delphi thread support.  Luckily, doesn't affect my apps.

Comment: @CosminPrund: Would you happen to have a QC report (number) for this? (Just to save me some digging :-)

Comment: "If it were a single pointer, then you might be able to replace
it, using a method that generates a full memory barrier
(example: InterlockedExchangePointer)" If it's a single pointer you can just write to it since aligned pointer sized reads/writes are atomic.

Comment: @David, edited the answer to talk a bit about the memory consistency model. That's the best I can do since I'm not convinced that the Intel memory model truly is strong enough. I made sure to make no recommendation in the answer, but for my own use I'll use Interlocked for such problems until I'm 100% certain I don't need to.

Comment: Cosmin, I can't repeat your problem with a race condition in `Classes.ThreadProc`. Can you share a test case?

Comment: @LURD, I'll try, but it's going to take some time. I'll need to deconstruct the one application where I had this problem, and that's going to be difficult because it's a 64bit Delphi application, I've only got Delphi XE2 and the debugger is not working for me anymore (Windows 8). At the time I implemented the mentioned fix I had very solid evidence that indeed my thread's `Execute` procedure exited, the Windows thread was shut down, yet the `Finished` flag stayed false. The problem's that getting the 64bit debugger is nowhere on my priority list.

Answer (score 2):

Beside more than register size, there are two operations involved. A check and later executed. To minimized, create a local var and use it. But anyway, this is still not 100% thread safe

```
var
  LNotify: TNotifyEvent;
begin
  ...
  LNotify := FOnNotify;
  if Assigned(LNotify) then
    LNotify(Self);
end;
```

Comment: `LNotify := FOnNotify` is not atomic. So, no dice.

Comment: @David - I guess it is to protect an assignment change after the 'Assigned' test and before calling the procedure.

Comment: @Sertac That's not enough though, is it?

Comment: @Sertac Except that bit is rather non-sensical. Thread safety is an either or thing. Code can't be 90% thread safe

Comment: In delphi is there any directive correspond "volatile" in C? Above code can be optimized easily to use directly FOnNotify instead of LOnNotify.

Comment: @BasePointer Delphi globals, record fields, object fields are always volatile. The code in this answer is pointless because the data is two pointers wide and so cannot be accessed atomically.

Comment: Yes but what would happen if that assignment was atomic? Accessing to native local variables by assuming that compiler will not optimize this line is a mistake too.